# Styling text part in flow document

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, paragraph

I have defined following in my XAML file:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <FlowDocument Name="FlowDocument1" PagePadding="10" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22">
        <Paragraph>
            Those who have denied the reality of moral distinctions, may be
            ranked among the disingenuous disputants; nor is it conceivable,
            that any human creature could ever seriously believe, that all
            characters and actions were alike entitled to the affection and
            regard of everyone. The difference, which nature has placed
            between one man and another, is so wide, and this difference is
            still so much farther widened, by education, example, and habit,
            that, where the opposite extremes come at once under our
            apprehension, there is no scepticism so scrupulous, and scarce
            any assurance so determined, as absolutely to deny all
            distinction between them. Let a man's insensibility be ever so
            great, he must often be touched with the images of Right and
            Wrong; and let his prejudices be ever so obstinate, he must
            observe, that others are susceptible of like impressions. The
            only way, therefore, of converting an antagonist of this kind, is
            to leave him to himself.
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

How can I in C#, for some text part defined in this paragraph, change background color or make it bold or italic ?

Comment: Will it be the same parts of the document every time? For instance, will "as absolutely to deny all distinction between them" always be italic, or will it be changed from normal to italic? Or do you need to change arbitrary words in the document at arbitrary times?

Comment: Is `<Run>` what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to modify it all the time. That means, I will probably change the paragraph content, or specific part in the paragraph...

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us I've never used FlowDocumentScrollViewer before, nor Run class. All I want is to see an example on how to access paragraph and change the content of it. For example: change the specific part of the text, change it to bold, italic, highlight.. Should I define name also for my Paragraph component inside FlowDocumentScrollViewer, or it is possible to say something like fd_Component.Document.Paragraph ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to treat your code like an xml file if you are familar with Nodes. The flow document is made up of blocks, with paragraphs, lines, etc.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners

So for example. your FlowDocument doesn;t have a name, so let's call it flowDocument1, so

```
flowDocument1.Blocks.Paragraph.Text = "Here"
```

Comment: Ok, I will set name for my FlowDocument right now in this code. However, let's back on to the question so that I can accept your answer. How can I for this paragraph change the specific part text to some other text, or make it bold or italic ?

Comment: You have to use find or a regex to find the specefic text you want and replace it with your new text